# How To Specify (Override) JQuery Icon Color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, icons

I've been making good use of the jQuery icons in my web app, but have come to a point where I would like to use a color that I'm not able to achieve by default. I'm currently using the "State Street" theme, which primarily uses green. But I have a red box with white text, and would like to use an icon that is white as well. There are white icons that are supplied with the theme, but they only get applied when the icons are inside a div (or some other container) that has a class of "ui-state-focus". This will make the icon white, but will change the background color to green, which I want to leave as red.

Is there any way (most likely via CSS) to override what background image jQuery uses for the icons, so that I can use a different color?

Thanks.

**CLARIFICATION:** I guess it would help for me to post the html I'm currently working with:

```
<!-- currently produces a default 'grey' icon color -->
<!-- this b/c no jquery ui class (like ui-state-focus) given for errorMessage div -->
<div id="errorMessage">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left"></span>
    Only 1 Activity can be added at a time 
</div>
```

I also have CSS:

```
.dialog #errorMessage
{
    /*display: none;*/
    background-color: #CC3300;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    bottom: auto;
    font-size: .80em;
    width: 100%
}
```

"display: none" is currently commented out so I can see it. I do have it set up to fadeIn on error catch. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: this question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588558/jqueryui-themeroller

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can overwrite the icons with the following CSS:

```
.ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(icons.png);
}
```

You can download the icon png file in any color you like. Just change the color part in the following url:

```
http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_*COLOR*_256x240.png
```

For example, if you want Red icons, and Cornflower Blue icons, the URLs you need are:

```
http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_ff0000_256x240.png
http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_6495ED_256x240.png
```

[image: Red] 
[image: Cornflower Blue]

etc.

(but don't use the URL as a CDN, be nice and save the files locally)

Comment: And if you want to use the color icons only in certain places, and leave the defaults for the rest, you can set your css classes as: ui-icon.redIcon { background-image: url(themes/altIcons/redIcons.png); } and refer to it in html with the classes "ui-icon-check redIcon"

Comment: I needed: "ui-icon ui-icon-check redIcon"

Comment: Know a way with the latest JQM?

Comment: That link still works, and is wonderful. Thank you for this, it really helped me out because there was no way to style the image icon.

Comment: Plus 1 for fight club reference on cornflower blue.

Answer (score 22):

**SELF-ANSWER:** Specified the background-image URL myself to be the file that uses the white icons. So I added a few lines to my CSS file:

```
.dialog #errorMessage .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(../../CSS/themes/custom_green/imag/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}
```

This essentially overrides the background image that the default jQuery css file wants to use for the icon, and achieved the color that I wanted. Of course this only worked because a white icon .png file was included with the theme. If I wanted some crazy color, like purple, I would have needed to create my own icon(s). Note that I needed to lengthen the URL in my own CSS file versus the URL that is specified in the jQuery CSS file, because they're located in two different places in my source.

Comment: i too found this. but is there a easy way to change the color of the icons?

Comment: Thanks for this!  I wanted to make my "delete" button icons red but leave the others as default.  Works like a champ, but hopefully they add a better way someday.

Comment: @KevinPauli They have; just add a class of the colour you want: `class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert Red"`

Answer (score 16):

Use built-in icon generator
for icon color #00a300  # dark green

```
.ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/?new=00a300&w=256&h=240&f=png&fltr[]=rcd|256&fltr[]=mask|icons/icons.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: Legend. I didn't know about this. I used http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/?new=ff0000&w=256&h=240&f=png&fltr[]=rcd|256&fltr[]=mask|icons/icons.png to generate a new set of red icons which I then added to the set of icons in my theme. 256 width and 240 height is the default icons file size (have a look in your themes image file)

Comment: I don't believe jQuery-UI wants their icon generator used as a CDN. I'm not sure if their server caches the images but it still has to generate that image when the cache is gone. It's not very nice to stress their server like that.... You should generate it once and save it on your server

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do that is to find out exactly what imagefile jQuery is using for the icons, and then modify that image file (or create your own) and drop it into place.

Comment: That would certainly work, but other parts of my page use classes that make use of the default grey icons, and do it appropriately. I wouldn't want to mess up those icons to achieve the white icon effect in only one place.

Answer (score 0):

buttons:[
text: //dont use this 
html:' No',"class":'bg-secondary text-white p-2 border-0',
click: function() { 
  $(this).dialog("close"); 
} 
]

Answer (score -2):

For locally stored css file in this case colour red:

```
<style>
#my_id .ui-icon {
  background-image: url(my_css_file_location/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png);
}
</style>}
```