# jqueryui themeroller

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm learning about the Framework Icons in jQuery UI.

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-minus"></span>
```

produces an icon of a minus sign inside a circle.
Using the ThemeRoller Firefox Bookmarklet, I was able to change the color of the icon to red (to make it look like a delete button).

Q: How can I make one jQueryUI icon be red and another one another color?

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>
```

I'd like to make this one green.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19121287/276093

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `ui-state-...` classes to change the state of the element with the icon.  You'll need to design your theme so that items in different states (highlight,hover,active,error,default) have different colors.

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus ui-state-highlight"></span>
```

I would recommend against using the states this way (just to change colors, that is).  I'd use the states semantically and let the icons render as needed to be consistent with the state.  If I specifically needed red/green icons, I'd generate those icons specifically as images and simply use them directly instead of trying to design the theme to get different color choices just for those icons.

For what it's worth, I think the [FamFamFam Silk](http://www.famfamfam.com/) icons integrate pretty well with jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about FamFamFam.

Comment: Have you got any more details on exactly how Silk + jQuery UI integration can be done?

Comment: @Alison - Integrate is probably the wrong word. I don't actually use the Silk icons in jQuery UI components, but rather use the icons alongside the jQuery UI components. From a design perspective they look good together.

Comment: thanks for clarifying :)  Does jQuery UI still display its own icons then?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, at least not in the context of ThemeRoller.  Themeroller uses one sprite image for this...a large image that contains all the Icons.

You can make another theme, same it's spritemap image to your images folder, and go into your jQuery UI CSS and change the `.ui-icon-circle-plus` `background-image` property.

It should look like this:

```
.ui-icon-circle-plus { background-position: 0 -192px; }
```

It would need to look something like this:

```
.ui-icon-circle-plus {
   background-image: url(RedIcons.png);
   background-position: 0 -192px; 
}
```

You can look at the `.ui-icon` styles for the image it's currently using.

Comment: I think ThemeRoller produces different sprites for each state.  I have 5 separate icon sprites in my themes anyway.  The sprites are all colored differently based on how you have the states set up.

Comment: @tvan - True, but only if one of his states is already red...in that case, still the same solution if he always wants the minus red, change the background image of that element (he just already has the image in that case...still much easier than editing the widgets).