# PrimeFaces how to change growl's closing icon color

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I work on PrimeFaces and I am trying to edit css properties of components. while working on growl, I am trying to change closing icon color but I just can't. I tried a lot and a lot and still couldn't figure out.

[image]

You can see at the top-right corner, Its background color yellow which I set it that but I cant change icon color. Its always that blue.  Here are my codes about growl;

```
.ui-growl{
    position:fixed;
    top:20%;
    left:38%;
    width: 23%;
}

.ui-growl .ui-state-highlight{
    background: #d2524f;
    border: #d2524f;

}

.ui-growl-message{      
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 2% 0 0 22%;
}

.ui-growl .ui-growl-icon-close{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Post version info, since from what I see, both answers are valid but depend on the PrimeFaces version used

Comment: PrimeFaces Version is 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closing icon is drawn with *background-image* attribute via the following CSS selector:

```css
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
  background-image: url("/showcase/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces-omega");
}
```

Changing the *color* attribute will have no effect. To change the icon color you have to modify the image url. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121287/3736575) gives some hints on that topic.

Tested with [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/).

Comment: I dont know is it correct in sense of ethic .s 

http://www.primefaces.org/icarus/messages.xhtml

In this page go Inspect Element  and you can see that its easy to change icon color and that code,@Angel Politis just send you can see it top. So how does it work in that icarus theme ?

Comment: Post  info for which PF version this valid

Comment: I look into library and it says PrimeFaces 5.0

Comment: @Bilal Your link points to a live demo of a premium theme. Premium themes seem to be different compared to standard themes. You did not mention you are using a premium theme in your project. If you are not using it in your project, i recomend to do inspection and testing with the standard [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/).

Comment: I see, I am not using the premium one. So I try to modify the image url.

Comment: The answerer shpuld post here which version he/she used. You did that for your question. Please put it in the question directly next time (or edit your question)

Comment: @Kukeltje Updated answer with reference to showcase.